# how to turn *.htm to *.php in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have read more than 3 questions here in stackoverflow about this, but all of them has one of the below problems:

- It redirects php to htm (not found appears, I already have php files in place)
- When you type *.htm, it will be redirected to *.php (I want visitors to see *.htm not *.php)

Let me boil it down for you guys: I need to type index.htm and apache redirects that to .php but in the address bar I still want to see .htm not .php

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: @ziesemer That will cause a redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ([^/]*)\.htm$ $1.php [PT]
```

Please review http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule for all of the available options, including other flags you may want to include - such as `QSA`.

Note that the `RewriteEngine on` line (as well as `Options FollowSymLinks` - see the docs linked to above) is necessary if you don't already have it elsewhere.  You may also need `AllowOverride FileInfo` in your primary Apache configuration to enable the use of `.htaccess` files.

Note that the `PT` flag is not strictly necessary, as it is the default if Apache determines it can fulfill the request without a redirect.

Here is another result I just found from a Google Search that shows pretty much the same thing I'm describing here:  http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php (specifically shows some rules around the .htm -> .php translation.)

Comment: As I told, It should not turn php to html in address bar, ofcourse I get "Object not found" error

Comment: This won't redirect the browser.  `PT` will direct Apache to proxy-through the request, so a request to the .htm will instead actually show the corresponding .php, if configured properly.

Comment: It seems I need to restart my server cause even with deleting htaccess I'm still getting redirected, maybe something has remained in the cache! tnx @ziesemer

Comment: R U sure this will work? because now when I type php everything is working, but when I type htm it'll cause: **Object not found**

Comment: Are you literally seeing "Object not found", or getting a HTTP 404 "Page Not Found"?  I did add the "RewriteEngine on" line to my answer, which is needed if you don't already have it elsewhere, and may have been over-assuming.  I have just tested this locally, and yes, I'm sure it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Hi it's easily done: In your .htaccess you will have a redirect like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).htm$     $1.php    [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$     $1.php    [QSA]
```

Comment: If you want to match both `htm` and `html`, use `html?`, not `html*`, or you'll also match `htmllllll`.  The `.` in `.html` needs to be escaped.  You should also add a trailing `$`, or this would also match anything that contains `html` **anywhere** within the URL.

Comment: You should add QSA to your answer though.